# Get daily consumption in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem on the consistency of my SQL QUERY. I want to get the Daily consumption of each day of the range specified in my query. My data per day is complete but if I run this query, I am lacking of data.

```
SELECT c.serialNo AS 'serialNo',  
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,b.[datetime],101) AS 'dteTime'  ,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,(CONVERT(MONEY,(MAX(a.normalenergy)))),1) AS 'prevnormalEnergy' , 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,(CONVERT(MONEY,(MAX(b.normalenergy)))),1) AS 'presnormalEnergy' , 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,(CONVERT(MONEY,((MAX(b.normalenergy) - MAX(a.normalenergy))))),1) AS 'presnormalConsumption'
FROM 
  Billing a, 
  Billing b, 
  tblMeterInfo c     
WHERE 
  a.[datetime] = b.[datetime] -1 AND 
  b.[datetime] = a.[datetime] + 1
AND 
  a.serialNo = b.serialNo AND 
  b.serialNo = c.serialNo AND 
  a.serialNo IN ('212583533') AND 
  b.[datetime] between '8/7/2014' AND '8/15/2014'
GROUP BY 
  b.serialNo, 
  c.serialNo,
  c.meterName,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.[datetime],101),  
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,b.[datetime],101) 
ORDER BY c.serialNo, CONVERT(VARCHAR,b.[datetime],101)
```

Output Missing dates **08/08/2014** to **08/09/2014**:

```
serialNo|dteTime|prevnormalEnergy|presnormalEnergy|presnormalConsumption

212583533|**08/07/2014**|10,928.41|11,067.81|139.40
212583533|**08/10/2014**|11,367.71|11,533.49|165.78
212583533|**08/11/2014**|11,533.49|11,702.62|169.13
212583533|**08/12/2014**|11,702.62|11,843.80|141.18
212583533|**08/13/2014**|11,843.80|11,989.22|145.42
212583533|**08/14/2014**|11,989.22|12,132.30|143.08
```

if I delete the **- 1** and **+ 1** on the WHERE clause, it displays all the result but I couldn't get the daily consumption of each date.

Output if `WHERE a.[datetime] = b.[datetime] AND b.[datetime] = a.[datetime]`:

```
serialNo|dteTime|prevnormalEnerg|presnormalEnergy|presnormalConsumption

212583533|**08/07/2014**|11,067.81|11,067.81|0.00
212583533|**08/08/2014**|11,214.35|11,214.35|0.00
212583533|**08/09/2014**|11,367.71|11,367.71|0.00
212583533|**08/10/2014**|11,533.49|11,533.49|0.00
212583533|**08/11/2014**|11,702.62|11,702.62|0.00
212583533|**08/12/2014**|11,843.80|11,843.80|0.00
212583533|**08/13/2014**|11,989.22|11,989.22|0.00
212583533|**08/14/2014**|12,132.30|12,132.30|0.00
```

Comment: Have you checked that there is no time component in either 8/8 ot 9/8 field in Billing.datetime?

Comment: I would also recommend using a.[datetime] = dateadd(day, -1, b.[datetime]) instead of a.[datetime] = b.[datetime] -1. Using shorthand can sometimes cause trouble when you think you know what it does when it actually means something else

Comment: Hi @JamesZ, what do you mean by time component? I guess the datetime is all the same.

Comment: okay @JamesZ, I'll try your recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: I mean that one record says "08/08/2014 00:01:00" instead of "08/08:2014 00:00:00" because your join conditions expect that the time is always the same, e.g. "00:00:00"

Comment: Also in where clause you have 2 similar compares. You can delete one of those

Comment: I tried your recommendation but I still got the missing dates.

Comment: Can you paste output with unformatted b.date and a.date when you delete +1 and -1?

Comment: Hi @GiorgiNakeuri, you mean I delete the conversion of dates?

Comment: Yes select jusr a.date and b.date while you delete +1

Comment: hi @GiorgiNakeuri, the date format is the only difference in the result. other than that the same rows are still the same. lacking of data

Comment: Paste output of this query:
`select [datetime] from Billing where [serialNo] IN ('212583533') and [datetime] between '8/7/2014' AND '8/15/2014'`

Comment: this is the output giorgi:

datetime
2014-08-08 06:00:07.000

2014-08-07 06:00:06.000

2014-08-09 06:00:06.000

2014-08-10 06:00:06.000

2014-08-11 06:00:06.000

2014-08-12 06:00:06.000

2014-08-13 06:00:06.000

2014-08-14 06:00:06.000